# error john the ripper on id_rsa conversion

Tags: hash, john-the-ripper

Why doesn't my conversion from id_rsa work?

I have an empty file in the final conversion idrsa.hash
and when I use command `cat idrsa.hash` to check the result is

```
ERRNO2 no such file or directory : id_rsa
```

impossible to convert the file with command

`usr/share/john/ssh2john.py id_rsa > idrsa.hash` the conversion in the file idrsa.hash have this result

```
ERRNO2 no such file or directory : id_rsa
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the full file path? The error you describe is `file not found`.

Comment: In particular if you generated the keyfile(s) with `ssh-keygen` by default that puts it/them in the directory `$HOME/.ssh` so if you are in your homedir the relative paths are `.ssh/id_rsa .ssh/id_dsa .ssh/id_ecdsa` etc.

Comment: When asking for help troubleshooting a command, don't describe what happens. Instead, put the command the the actual full result of the output